# Why do some apps still get push notifications when there's no data?

Tags: mobile-data, push-notifications

I have both Facebook and Instagram blocked from using data on my phone (only WiFi), but I still get push notifications from them when not on WiFi. How and why is this happening, and how do I stop it?